# wordpress https login redirects to woocommerce account

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, account

I have a typical wordpress site with SSL certificate.
After installing the cert. and activate https, I can't no longer login to the backend. I am not using any services like cloudflare etc.

When I do a login (from woocommerce login page), it automatically redirects me to a woocommerce profile site, even though I have administrator rights.

Strangely when I deactivate https, it redirects me to the backend as it should.

What I have tried:

**1) Deactivate plugins to make sure there is no conflicts**

**2) Adding following to my functions.php:**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_prevent_admin_access', '__return_false' );
```

**3) Adding following to config.php file:**

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

**4) Changing the siteurl from:**

```
http://mysitedomain.com
```

to:

```
https://mysitedomain.com
```

Nothing above with any luck. Somehow https issue.
Any thoughts? :)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that If I just entered yousitedomain.com/wp-login.php instead of wp-admin, all works perfect. I hope this can help somebody :)